# Como fazer impressora bematech cortar a impressão no meio?

Tags: delphi, impressão, relatório, report-builder

Estou implementando um relatório no Report Builder em Delphi e preciso que no meio da impressão, a impressora (Bematech - Impressora não fiscal MP 4200 TH) faça um corte e continue na mesma impressão.

Alguém sabe qual componente ou comando eu utilizo no report builder para que o mesmo identifique um corte no papel?

Estou tentando usar o componente 'line', pois pensei que o mesmo teria alguma propriedade que corta-se o papel no momento que ela é desenhada.

Comment: Não existe propriedade para fazer isso. Talvez você consiga enviar o relatório como texto puro e enviar uma string com o comando para o corte conforme mencionado na resposta do woliveirajr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu achei o seguinte site que ensina como fazer : [Acinonando a guilhotina na minimpressora não fiscal](http://partners.bematech.com.br/2011/06/edicao-75-acionando-a-guilhotina-na-minimpressora-nao-fiscal/)

Basicamente, se for utilizando a DLL da impressora, você enviará o seguinte comando após ter feito as declarações adequadas:

```
//ACIONAMENTO DA GUILHOTINA

sComando := #27 + #119;
iRetorno := ComandoTX( sComando, Length( sComando );
```

Se for via driver de impressora, você deve configurar as propriedades da impressora para fazer um corte ao final da impressão ou inserir o comando <1B>w em determinada caixas de propriedade

Comment: Mas como se usa o ReportBuilder para acessar a DLL?